# Suppressing errors from an embedded command in a batch file for loop

Tags: windows, command-line, batch, batch-file

I have a batch file that uses the `for` command to parse the output from another command, but I want all errors written to STDERR to be suppressed.

I have tried this:

```
for /F "usebackq delims=" %%a in (`mycommand.exe 2>nul`) do set RESULT=%%a
```

in which I'm attempting to redirect STDERR to nul for the inner embedded command, but I get this error:

```
2> was unexpected at this time.
```

How can I ignore all errors generated by `mycommand.exe`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Solution

The [redirection operator](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490982.aspx) must be escaped:

```
for /F "usebackq delims=" %%a in (`mycommand.exe 2^>nul`) do set RESULT=%%a
```

### Further reading

- [Batch files - Escape Characters](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/escapechars.php)